# Turning array back into variables PHP

Tags: php, arrays, escaping

I have put 17 variables into an array, and then ran `mysqli_real_escape_string` on them, as it's much easier than having to do it for each variable individually.

```
$rescape = array($username, $fname, $lname, $nationality, $landline, $mobile, $email, $nationalid, $passport, $dob, $street, $towncity, $postcode, $country, $country, $favourite, $rentpw);
$rescape = array_map('mysqli_real_escape_string', $rescape);
```

If I understand correctly, now the escaped strings are all stored inside the array in `$rescape`.

What is the 'shortest' method of getting them back into individual variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with `list`:

```
list($username, $fname, $lname, $nationality, $landline, $mobile, $email, $nationalid, $passport, $dob, $street, $towncity, $postcode, $country, $country, $favourite, $rentpw) = $rescape;
```

You can even use [`extract`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) if you store `$rescape` as a key/value pair.

---

Be aware that `mysqli_real_escape_string` needs as first parameter the link of the connection. Something like this:

```
$rescape = array_map(function($e) use ($connection) {
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $e);
}, $rescape);
```

or, if you're using mysqli in Object oriented style, just

```
$rescape = array_map(array($mysqli, 'real_escape_string'), $rescape);
```

should do the trick.

Comment: `$rescape = array_map($connection, 'mysqli_real_escape_string', $rescape);` like so?

Comment: I've added an example in the answer

Comment: How come I don't need to include `mysqli_` on `real_escape_string` in example 2?

Comment: In the first example you have `mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $e)`. In my case, is the connection (`$connection`) meant to be in **just** that first parameter? e,g: `mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $e)` (I am confused as the function uses `$mysqli` too)

Comment: yeah - I've renamed it just to avoid confusion

Comment: Thanks, you are also missing a semi-colon on the end of mysqli_real_escape_string but it won't let me edit it myself